# <b>admin </b> prevent himself to drop specific tables?

Tags: sql-server-2008

How can **admin**  prevent himself  to drop or truncate  specific tables,  because sometimes a table is accidently truncated or deleted,   making view is not a good idea. if i make a trigger ,it is implemented in all tables in db. i just want to implement it in specific tables, in sql server ?

Comment: you can write a trigger on that specific table

Comment: can you give some example how , i searched but not found it for specific table drop or truncate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Create TRIGGER [TR_ProtectCriticalTables]
ON DATABASE 
FOR 
DROP_TABLE

AS    
DECLARE @eventData XML,
    @uname NVARCHAR(50),
    @oname NVARCHAR(100),
    @otext VARCHAR(MAX),
    @etype NVARCHAR(100),
    @edate DATETIME
SET @eventData = eventdata()
SELECT
    @edate=GETDATE(),
    @uname=@eventData.value('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/UserName)[1]', 'SYSNAME'),
    @oname=@eventData.value('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'SYSNAME'),
    @otext=@eventData.value('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]', 
            'VARCHAR(MAX)'),
    @etype=@eventData.value('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
  IF @oname IN ('tbluser')-- You can give comma seperated list here
BEGIN
DECLARE @err varchar(100)
SET @err = 'Table ' + @oname  + ' is super duper protected and cannot be dropped.'
RAISERROR (@err, 16, 1) ;
ROLLBACK;
END
GO
ENABLE TRIGGER [TR_ProtectCriticalTables] ON DATABASE
```

For disabling the truncate try this

```
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table
@source_schema = N'dbo',
@source_name = N'TestTable',
@role_name = NULL
GO
```

This may cause some other problems so please check before using.

Comment: i think this will be implemented on all tables,

Comment: no "IF @oname IN ('tbluser')" here you can specify the comma seperated list of tables that you want not to be deleted.

Comment: TRUNCATE can be prevented if a FOREIGN KEY exists to the table,so you could create an empty table with a FK constriant to the tables you want to protect from accidental truncation.

I don't think there is a way to prevent TRUNCATE by a trigger

Comment: thanks @anshuman  but is there any other way then using foreign key

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the permissions dir that special admins. And create a second user which has the permissions for doing such dangerous jobs.

See also the [GRANT and REVOKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) SQL commands.

Comment: @puneet about truncate permission: TRUNCATE TABLE empties a table completely. It requires the DROP privilege as of MySQL 5.1.16. (Before 5.1.16, it requires the DELETE privilege).

Comment: i have admin rights ,now i want that some specific tables can not be truncated accidently, if i want to truncate them i have to forcefully fo this, one way is bt using foreign key constraint in other table , but i don't want to do this

Answer (score 0):

Please create user and create trigger for superadmin who has all permissions like :

```
CREATE TRIGGER reminder2
ON Customer
with execute as owner
AFTER  DELETE 
AS
  truncate table Customer
```

Comment: first you craete new user and this user to give rights to whatever you like..truncate or delete..

Comment: i was assuming to prevent admin to truncate a specific table